# Passing parameters on JQuery .trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery trigger but am not sure what the correct syntax is to pass parameters in my situation.  Here is where I am making the call :

```
$('#'+controlName).trigger(event);
```

Here is where I am doing the event binding :

```
$(window).on('onPartialRendered', onPartialRendered);
```

And here is my event handler :

```
var onPartialRendered = function () {

    .....
};
```

Everything works fine until I try to pass parameters.  What would be the correct way to do it as per my example?

Comment: Yes, I tried passing params using the syntax there trigger(event, ['Param1', 'Param2']) but without any success

Comment: Your `onPartialRendered` doesn't have any parameters in its signature.  It should be `onPartialRendered = function(e, p1, p2)`.

Comment: @user517406 how did you try to pass the parameters which did not work?

Comment: @user517406 try to post some code in jsfiddle.net for us to play with.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

First parameter is always string with event name and next parameters are additional data:

```
.trigger('foo', [1, 2]);

.on('foo', function(event, one, two) { ... });
```

Special thanks for Rocket Hazmat

#### Example:

```
var controller = {
  listen: function (event, json, string) {}
};

$('body').trigger('this_works', [{data: [1, 2, 3]}, 'something']);

$('body').on('this_works', function (event, json, string) {
  controller.listen(event, json, string);
});
```

#### Remote partial:

Please do not use this way. There is many article about this problem in network. This take much time and generate unnecessary traffic in network. Please use this way:

```
var template = $('#templates #example_template').detach();
var clone = template.clone();
clone.find('.some_field').val('new_data');
clone.attr('id', null);
$('table tbody').append(clone);
```

Comment: Not quite.  `.trigger` only takes 2 arguments.  You need to pass an array (or object) of parameters.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax if I wanted to separate the event binding from the event handler like in my example?

Comment: Can you please give a syntax example, using this syntax does not work : EVENT BINDING $(window).on('onPartialRendered', onPartialRendered(p1, p2)); EVENT HANDLER var onPartialRendered = function (p1, p2) { ... }

Comment: @user517406 That's entirely the wrong way to pass a function reference as an event handler. Add the parameters where you are **defining** the function. `var onPartialRendered = function (event,one,two) {`

Comment: Thanks, just thought that I should have parameters defined somewhere in the event binding, but clearly not :)

Comment: Simply change the trigger to this: $('body').trigger({type:'this_works', data:[1,2,3], message: 'something'});. The handler can still just have function(event) in it and get the parameters by stating event.data and event.message.

Comment: can i put dynamic data on trigger parameters ...and how