# How exactly do you pass data for jQuery's trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

According to their API (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), you should be able to do it just like this:

```
    $("body").trigger({
      type:"logged",
      user:"foo",
      pass:"bar"
    });
```

However, I tried a few examples below, and the data never passed if I call it through `trigger()`...

http://jsfiddle.net/totszwai/XExe9/

Comment: As a sidenote, jQuery's event handling system wasn't really made for javascript classes and instances, but DOM elements, did you try it with actual nodes ?

Comment: As noone else seems to answer I'll try. `event.data` is always undefined in your examples, it's used for something completely different, passing data in the event handler. You're passing arbitrary data with trigger and you just have to check for that data, not `event.data`

Comment: I can call `trigger` for custom javascript objects. When you do `$(YOUROBJECT).on("blah")`, jQuery will add its necessary stuff to the custom object. If you try to `resize` the window, it won't be undefined.

Comment: Well, you're doing it wrong, I've added an answer to try and explain why

Comment: For passing data from the trigger() call to the on() event handler SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16401574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking for `event.data`, which is undefined in all your examples

```
this.resize = function(event) {
    if (event.data) {
        console.log("with data " + event.type + " : " + event.data.toString());    
    } else {
        console.log("without data " + event.type);
    }
}
```

`event.data` is when you pass data to the event handler

```
$('element').on('click', {'event' : 'data', 'goes' : 'here'}, function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.goes);  // here
});
```

^ that's `event.data`, and you're not using it, here's the documentation for that

**http://api.jquery.com/event.data/**

What you want is something more like

```
this.resize = function(event) {
    if (event.test1) {
        console.log(event.test1)
        console.log(event.test2)
        console.log(event.test3)
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XExe9/14/)

And note that even if you define a `data` property, it will not overwrite the `event.data` property, as that's protected internally by jQuery, so this will fail

```
$(element).trigger({
     type : 'click',
     data : 'test' // never passed
});
```

And that's to keep the `event.data` behaviour that jQuery provides from being overwritten.

In other words, you're confusing `event.data` with passing arbitrary  data in `trigger()`

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're missing the eventType

```
$("body").trigger("click", {
    type:"logged",
    user:"foo",
    pass:"bar"
});
```

Comment: I have the type set in every case.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use `trigger`, and it works for me:

```
$("body").bind('someEvent', function (e, arg1, arg2) {
    alert('arg1: ' + arg1);
    alert('arg2: ' + arg2);
});

$("body").trigger('someEvent', ['arg1_text', 'arg2_text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#logo').trigger('myEvent', "Hello!");

$('#logo').on('myEvent',(e, data) => {
   console.log(e.data); // <--- this is undefined
   console.log(data);  // <--- data === "Hello!"
});
```

Use second argument in callback. Not `e.data` which is `undefined`