# Print the arguments inside a handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Passing parameters on JQuery .trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401538/passing-parameters-on-jquery-trigger)

The passed arguments are unable to display,
I get undefined even if the arguments are passed. How do I alert the passed arguments when a button is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn1").on('click', function(event, one, two) { 
alert(one)
});
});

$("#btn1").trigger('click', [1, 2]);

</script>
<button id="btn1">Click here to display args passed</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by bellow code.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $("#myBtn").on('click',{ extra : 'you parameter value' }, function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    myFunction(data.extra);
  });
})

function myFunction(parameter)
{
  alert(parameter)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
```